# lim sup of a sequence of postive numbers is equal to lim inf of the inverses of the numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers.

Prove that:
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac1{x_n} = \frac1{\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n}$$

I don´t know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$\frac1x$ is decreasing and continuous on your domain.
Use this to estimate the two sides
$$LHS\le RHS\le LHS$$

Comment: Ok, i don´t know if in the original sequence the terms are increasing or decreasing, i think that you are sugesting me that after use the Bolzano Weieratrass theorem, i should use that hint right?

Comment: If you have that, you can use it ;-)

Comment: yes i have that theorem, but i don´t see the trick

Comment: @Julio Use it to obtain a non-increasing subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is almost obvious from the definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

If $\liminf x_{n} = x$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $x_{n} > x - \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$ and $x_{n} < x + \epsilon$ for an infinity of values of $n$.

If $\limsup y_{n} = y$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $y_{n} < y + \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$ and $y_{n} > y - \epsilon$ for an infinity of values of $n$.

Clearly if we put $y_{n} = 1/x_{n}$ with $x_{n} \neq 0$ for all $n$ and if $\liminf x_{n} = x$ and we take reciprocal in one definition then from the above definitions it is easily seen that $\limsup y_{n} = 1/x = 1/\liminf x_{n}$.